# Adding path variable in wsl

Tags: path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

I have added a path in bashrc, still, the command is not found. When tried in ubuntu it worked but not in WSL. Why this happen?.

export PATH=\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\local\mbdyn\bin:$PATH

added same path in .bashrc

error: command not found

**Please see the attached image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that questions here should be about "*specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.*"  Please consider posting questions like this on [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](https://superuser.com) in the future.  Short answer, though, your path is incorrect in at least two ways - Linux paths use `/`, not `\`.  And you should start from `/usr/` since that's the Linux path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify the PATH variable as follows:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mbdyn/bin"
```

Answer (score 19):

As you have been told, the forward slash to use is / and if you use the command

```
PATH="$PATH:/folder/subfolder/"
```

that value will only last in the PATH for the duration of the session.
To include a value in the PATH permanently, edit the .bashrc file from your home

```
$ sudo vim ~/.bashrc
```

you add at the end

```
export PATH="$PATH:/folder/subfolder/"
```

you save and you will have that value in the PATH in each session

Comment: This should be the answer given its extra details which enforces the path each time we load linux

Comment: It didn't work for me. There was no .bashrc file so I had to create it, after which I followed similar instructions. 
Here's the version I'm using 
`$ bash --version`  
`GNU bash, version 4.4.12(0)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)`

Comment: Suppose I want to add multiple folders to the path, what's the syntax for that?